# How can I use Regex to find a string of characters in alphabetical order using Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I have a challenge I'm working on - find the longest string of alphabetical characters in a string. For example, "abcghiijkyxz" should result in "ghiijk" (Yes the i is doubled).

I've been doing quite a bit with loops to solve the problem - iterating over the entire string, then for each character, starting a second loop using lower and ord. No help needed writing that loop.

However, it was suggested to me that Regex would be great for this sort of thing. My regex is weak (I know how to grab a static set, my look-forwards knowledge extends to knowing they exist). How would I write a Regex to look forward, and check future characters for being next in alphabetical order? Or is the suggestion to use Regex not practical for this type of thing?

Edit: The general consensus seems to be that Regex is indeed terrible for this type of thing.

Comment: Regex isn't practical for this kind of thing.

Comment: Regex is a ___terrible___ choice for this. Regex has no concept of "this letter comes after this letter in the alphabet"; trying to solve this with regex is like trying to do math with regex.

Comment: You could see if someone over at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ is crazy enough to come up with a solution in regex

Comment: Well, this seems to neatly validate my initial "Wait, REALLY!?" reaction. For this type of question, with the answer being "No, this is a terrible idea", what's the best way to indicate that the question's closed/solved?

Comment: Excellent question. I suppose you could answer it (..!!) and add your current code as "the right way". That, or delete the question in its entirety (consider it might be helpful for others).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to demonstrate why regex is **not** practical for this sort of thing, here is a regex that would match `ghiijk` in your given example of `abcghiijkyxz`. Note it'll also match `abc`, `y`, `x`, `z` since they should technically be considered for longest string of alphabetical characters in order. Unfortunately, you can't determine which is the longest with regex alone, but this does give you all the possibilities. Please note that this regex works for PCRE and will not work with python's `re` module! Also, note that [python's `regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) library does not currently support `(*ACCEPT)`. Although I haven't tested, the [pyre2 package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/) (python wrapper for Google's re2 pyre2 using Cython) claims it [supports the `(*ACCEPT)` control verb](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), so this *may* currently be possible using python.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RxR4Va/6)

```
((?:a+(?(?!b)(*ACCEPT))|b+(?(?!c)(*ACCEPT))|c+(?(?!d)(*ACCEPT))|d+(?(?!e)(*ACCEPT))|e+(?(?!f)(*ACCEPT))|f+(?(?!g)(*ACCEPT))|g+(?(?!h)(*ACCEPT))|h+(?(?!i)(*ACCEPT))|i+(?(?!j)(*ACCEPT))|j+(?(?!k)(*ACCEPT))|k+(?(?!l)(*ACCEPT))|l+(?(?!m)(*ACCEPT))|m+(?(?!n)(*ACCEPT))|n+(?(?!o)(*ACCEPT))|o+(?(?!p)(*ACCEPT))|p+(?(?!q)(*ACCEPT))|q+(?(?!r)(*ACCEPT))|r+(?(?!s)(*ACCEPT))|s+(?(?!t)(*ACCEPT))|t+(?(?!u)(*ACCEPT))|u+(?(?!v)(*ACCEPT))|v+(?(?!w)(*ACCEPT))|w+(?(?!x)(*ACCEPT))|x+(?(?!y)(*ACCEPT))|y+(?(?!z)(*ACCEPT))|z+(?(?!$)(*ACCEPT)))+)
```

Results in:

```
abc
ghiijk
y
x
z
```

Explanation of a single option, i.e. `a+(?(?!b)(*ACCEPT))`:

- `a+` Matches `a` (literally) one or more times. This catches instances where several of the same characters are in sequence such as `aa`.
- `(?(?!b)(*ACCEPT))` If clause evaluating the condition.

  - `(?!b)` Condition for the if clause. Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is **not** `b`. This is because if it's not `b`, we want the following control verb to take effect.
  - `(*ACCEPT)` If the condition (above) is met, we *accept* the current solution. This control verb causes the regex to end successfully, skipping the rest of the pattern. Since this token is inside a capturing group, only that capturing group is ended successfully at that particular location, while the parent pattern continues to execute.

So what happens if the condition is not met? Well, that means that `(?!b)` evaluated to false. This means that the following character is, in fact, `b` and so we allow the matching (rather capturing in this instance) to continue. Note that the entire pattern is wrapped in `(?:)+` which allows us to match consecutive options until the `(*ACCEPT)` control verb or end of line is met.

The only exception to this whole regular expression is that of `z`. Being that it's the last character in the English alphabet (which I presume is the target of this question), we don't care what comes after, so we can simply put `z+(?(?!$)(*ACCEPT))`, which will ensure nothing matches after `z`. If you, instead, want to match `za` (circular alphabetical order matching - idk if this is the proper terminology, but it sounds right to me) you can use `z+(?(?!a)(*ACCEPT)))+` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/RxR4Va/7).

Comment: I love your solution, it's very well written! Given that the problem doesn't loop z to a (Thankfully), it's kinda moot, but I was wondering - you mentioned the string at the end to loop Z to A, but it doesn't look like it'd register ZAB as a string - it would just give ZA. A possible additional point in why regex is bad for this? (Imagine trying to do a-za-za-z for example....)

Comment: @Selkie thank you :) I made a quick little edit to make the link more apparent at the end. See my edit with the link [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/RxR4Va/7) in it (at the very end). It includes an example where `zzaabcddde` is fully matched. To only match `a-z` you'd use the regex I posted above, but to match `a-z` circularly you would use the `z+(?(?!a)(*ACCEPT)))+` subpattern as the link shows.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should upvote this, for showing that it's possible, or downvote, because it shows how to. This is brilliant!

Comment: @jpaugh thanks, I posted this and honestly, I’m in the same boat as you. I like it but I don’t

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, regex is not the best tool for this. Since you are interested in a continuous sequence, you can do this with a single for loop:

```
def LNDS(s):
    start = 0
    cur_len = 1
    max_len = 1
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        if ord(s[i]) in (ord(s[i-1]), ord(s[i-1])+1):
            cur_len += 1
        else:
            if cur_len > max_len:
                max_len = cur_len
                start = i - cur_len
            cur_len = 1
    if cur_len > max_len:
        max_len = cur_len
        start = len(s) - cur_len
    return s[start:start+max_len]

>>> LNDS('abcghiijkyxz')
'ghiijk'
```

We keep a running total of how many non-decreasing characters we have seen, and when the non-decreasing sequence ends we compare it to the longest non-decreasing sequence we saw previously, updating our "best seen so far" if it is longer.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers the same problem, given the asker's test string and desired result: they want the longest sequence of alphabetically _consecutive_ characters, allowing repeats.

Comment: Can you make a demo on Ideone ? I tested and it's not returning correct result.

Comment: I mean, I appreciate the "solved" code, but I'm hoping to finish writing it myself - good learning experience and all that :)

Comment: @Imran: Check this https://ideone.com/pWfsIF . Results are inconsistent.

Comment: OK, it was a problem with the final check. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Generate all the regex substrings like ^a+b+c+$ (longest to shortest).
Then match each of those regexs against all the substrings (longest to shortest) of "abcghiijkyxz" and stop at the first match.

```
def all_substrings(s):
    n = len(s)
    for i in xrange(n, 0, -1):
        for j in xrange(n - i + 1):
            yield s[j:j + i]

def longest_alphabetical_substring(s):
    for t in all_substrings("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
        r = re.compile("^" + "".join(map(lambda x: x + "+", t)) + "$")
        for u in all_substrings(s):
            if r.match(u):
                return u

print longest_alphabetical_substring("abcghiijkyxz")
```

That prints "ghiijk".

Comment: This is both ridiculous and strangely beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex**: `char+` meaning `a+b+c+...`

Details:

- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**Python code**:

```
import re

def LNDS(text):
    array = []

    for y in range(97, 122):  # a - z
        st = r"%s+" % chr(y)
        for x in range(y+1, 123):  # b - z
            st += r"%s+" % chr(x)
            match = re.findall(st, text)

            if match:
                array.append(max(match, key=len))
            else:
                break

        if array:
            array = [max(array, key=len)]

    return array
```

**Output**:

```
print(LNDS('abababababab abc')) >>> ['abc']
print(LNDS('abcghiijkyxz')) >>> ['ghiijk']
```

For string `abcghiijkyxz` regex pattern:

```
a+b+                    i+j+k+l+
a+b+c+                  j+k+
a+b+c+d+                j+k+l+
b+c+                    k+l+
b+c+d+                  l+m+
c+d+                    m+n+
d+e+                    n+o+
e+f+                    o+p+
f+g+                    p+q+
g+h+                    q+r+
g+h+i+                  r+s+
g+h+i+j+                s+t+
g+h+i+j+k+              t+u+
g+h+i+j+k+l+            u+v+
h+i+                    v+w+
h+i+j+                  w+x+
h+i+j+k+                x+y+
h+i+j+k+l+              y+z+
i+j+
i+j+k+
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/BQKFG4844)

Comment: @Rawing I agree. I just gave an idea of how it can be done using regex and some coding. My post is not finished, so...

Comment: I can see the outline of what you're proposing, and I get it, it makes sense. Question is - is this significantly different from a simple ord(s)+1==ord(s+1)? If so, how? If not, what tangible benefit is there to using regex over ord?

Comment: @Rawing Updated.

Answer (score 0):

To actually "solve" the problem, you could use

```
string = 'abcxyzghiijkl'

def sort_longest(string):
    stack = []; result = [];

    for idx, char in enumerate(string):
        c = ord(char)
        if idx == 0:
            # initialize our stack
            stack.append((char, c))
        elif idx == len(string) - 1:
            result.append(stack)
        elif c == stack[-1][1] or c == stack[-1][1] + 1:
            # compare it to the item before (a tuple)
            stack.append((char, c))
        else:
            # append the stack to the overall result
            # and reinitialize the stack
            result.append(stack)
            stack = []
            stack.append((char, c))

    return ["".join(item[0]
        for item in sublst) 
        for sublst in sorted(result, key=len, reverse=True)]

print(sort_longest(string))
```

Which yields

```
['ghiijk', 'abc', 'xyz']
```

in this example.

---

The idea is to loop over the string and keep track of a `stack` variable which is filled by your requirements using `ord()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy with regexps!

(Using trailing contexts here)

```
rexp=re.compile(
    "".join(['(?:(?=.' + chr(ord(x)+1) + ')'+ x +')?'
            for x in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"])
    +'[a-z]')

a = 'bcabhhjabjjbckjkjabckkjdefghiklmn90'

re.findall(rexp, a)

#Answer: ['bc', 'ab', 'h', 'h', 'j', 'ab', 'j', 'j', 'bc', 'k', 'jk', 'j', 'abc', 'k', 'k', 'j', 'defghi', 'klmn']
```