# Regex for three letters and four numbers?

Tags: regex, validation

I have this regex I am supposed to create that accepts the following formats:

1. Any 3 letters (case-insensitive, no other characters except for alphabetic characters)
2. Any 2 letters with a dash in between (case-insensitive)
3. Any 4 digits

This is what I have come up with so far: `^([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|-)[a-zA-Z])|[0-9]{4}$`

The issue with this regex is that it accepts a combination of 4 letters as well, but I only want three consecutive letters. What do I need to change in my regex to accomplish this?

Comment: 3 consecutive letters means `abc`, `bcd`, `cde`, etc.?

Comment: @Barmar yes, exactly!

Comment: But not `ace` because they're not consecutive in the alphabet, right?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I misunderstood your comment before. things like ace should work, snk, lbd, etc all those should be able to work. I meant just a a sequence of all letters.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588490/how-can-i-use-regex-to-find-a-string-of-characters-in-alphabetical-order-using-p/48589051#48589051) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880088/regular-expression-to-match-3-or-more-consecutive-sequential-characters-and-cons/8880125) on consecutive letters in regex. It's not something that is easily accomplished and, quite frankly, is not a great idea.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 4):

You may use:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{4})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYUmJ5/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group that match either of these 2 alternatives

  - `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z]`: Match 3 letters or a `letter-letter`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[0-9]{4}`: Match 4 digits
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose your alternations in a group so that the anchors apply to all of them:

```
^(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z])|[0-9]{4})$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/U47gFj/3/)

Note that you can simply include `-` in your second character class in the first alternation as `[a-zA-Z-]` is equivalent to `([a-zA-Z]|-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first alternative that matches letters only has the `^` anchor, so it just checks that the input begins with 3 letters or 2 letters separated by hyphen.

Your second alternative only has `$` anchor, so it just checks thatthe end of the input is 4 digits.

You need to put both anchors in both alternatives.

```
^([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|-)[a-zA-Z])$|^[0-9]{4}$
```

or put another group around everything except the anchors.

```
^(([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|-)[a-zA-Z])|[0-9]{4})$
```

Comment: `([a-zA-Z]|-)` is same as `[a-zA-Z-]`

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your regex using character classes and modifiers to make your pattern more concise:

For example, in JavaScript Syntax, this would be

`/\d{4}|[a-z]([a-z]|-)[a-z]/ig`

- `\d` is short for digits [0-9]
- `i` stands for case-insensitive
- `g` stands for global, which will match all occurences, not just the first

[See example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I05CLr/1)

```js
const pattern = /\d{4}|[a-z]([a-z]|-)[a-z]/ig

const test = (desc, str) => {
  const match = (str.match(pattern) || []).join(', ')
  console.log(desc, '\n', str, '→', match, match ? '✓' : '×')
}

test('Any 3 letters (case-insensitive, no other characters except for alphabetic characters)', 'fourhundredandfive')
test('Any 2 letters with a dash in between (case-insensitive)', 'no-one')
test('Any 4 digits', 'ab 1234567 ab')
```